Name for a nonlinear first order Partial Differential Equation
The ordinary Schrödinger equation reads:
$$i \hbar \frac{\partial \Psi(\mathbf{r}, t)}{\partial t} = -\frac{\hbar^2 \nabla^2}{2m} \Psi(\mathbf{r}, t) + V(\mathbf{r}, t) \Psi(\mathbf{r}, t)$$
Physically, though, all that is observable is the probability density $\rho(\mathbf{r}, t) = \Psi \Psi^* .$ This leads to the natural question: can a differential equation be formulated for $\rho$ directly? Such a question has been asked here, with answer:

Let $\psi=\sqrt{\rho}\mathrm e^{iS}$, with $\rho,S$ a pair of real
variables. You may write the Schrödinger equation directly in terms of
$\rho,S$ as (cf.
Madelung
or
Bohm)
\begin{equation} \begin{aligned} \frac{\partial\sqrt{\rho}}{\partial t}&=-\frac{1}{2m}\left(\sqrt{\rho}\nabla^2S+2\nabla\sqrt{\rho}\cdot\nabla S\right)\\ \frac{\partial S}{\partial t}&=-\left(\frac{|\nabla
 S|^2}{2m}+V-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\nabla^2\sqrt{\rho}}{\sqrt{\rho}}\right) \end{aligned} \end{equation} ... Formally speaking, you may solve the equation for $S$ as a
functional of $\rho$, and plug the result into the equation for
$\rho$, thus obtaining an equation for $\rho$ alone.

I want to look at this in more detail. The first equation can be rewritten
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = -\frac{1}{m} \left(\rho \nabla^2 S + \nabla \rho \cdot \nabla S\right)$$
where I have ignored for the time being any potential worries about places where $\rho =0.$ Then the second equation can be rewritten
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}+\frac{\nabla S \cdot \nabla S}{2m}=-V+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho}}\nabla^2\sqrt{\rho}$$
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}+\frac{\nabla S \cdot \nabla S}{2m}=-V+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho}}\left[\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\rho}}\left( \nabla^2 \rho - \frac{\nabla \rho \cdot \nabla \rho}{\rho}\right) \right]$$
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}+\frac{\nabla S \cdot \nabla S}{2m}=-V+\frac{\hbar^2}{4m \rho}\left( \nabla^2 \rho - \frac{\nabla \rho \cdot \nabla \rho}{\rho}\right)$$
Let's invent some notation and write this as:
$$\mathcal{J}[S] = \tilde{\mathcal{H}}[\rho,V]$$
where
$$\mathcal{J} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \frac{(\nabla \cdot) (\nabla \cdot)}{2m},$$
and $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}[\rho,V]$ is the right hand side of the equation.
Then, for a given $V, \rho,$ I will denote a solution to the above equation with the notation:
$$S=\mathcal{J}^{-1}[\tilde{\mathcal{H}}[V,\rho]]$$
We now have an (ugly) partial differential equation for $\rho$ alone:
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = -\frac{1}{m} \left(\rho \nabla^2 (\mathcal{J}^{-1}[\tilde{\mathcal{H}}[V,\rho]]) + \nabla \rho \cdot \nabla (\mathcal{J}^{-1}[\tilde{\mathcal{H}}[V,\rho]])\right)$$

Is there any name for the previous partial differential equation?
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}+\frac{\nabla S \cdot \nabla S}{2m}=-V+\frac{\hbar^2}{4m \rho}\left( \nabla^2 \rho - \frac{\nabla \rho \cdot \nabla \rho}{\rho}\right)$$
More simply,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + a (\nabla f) \cdot (\nabla f) = g(x,y,z,t),$$
or even in one dimension:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + a \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)^2 = g(x,t).$$
where $a$ is a constant and $g$ is arbitrary (We can assume that $g \geq 0$ everywhere). What about solution methods?

To my knowledge, there is no universally accepted name for this equation.
Let $g\geq 0$. The steady state analogue of your equation (i.e. assuming the solution does not depend on $t$) is $$ \vert \nabla u \vert = F \tag{$\ast$}  $$ with $$F =  \sqrt{\frac{g(x)}a},  $$ which is known as the Eikonal equation, so it would be reasonable to refer to your equation as an evolution Eikonal equation. Unfortunately, when I search this phrase it didn't immediately return anything other than references for $(\ast)$, but I didn't do a thorough search.
Moreover, in the paper The relation between the porous medium and Eikonal equations in several space dimensions by Lions, Souganidis, Vázquez, they refer to the equation $$v_t = \vert \nabla v \vert^2 $$ as the Eikonal equation. Your equation is the same as theirs with $v=-f$ and an additional forcing term, so it may be reasonable to just refer your PDE is the Eikonal equation, but, again, this may lead to confusion with the usual Eikonal equation $(\ast)$.
More generally, it is an example of a first order fully nonlinear PDE, so searching this phrase may help.

+1, and it would be commendable if OP would sketch how he or she ran into this pde.

@Aruralreader I've now done so
